# Spring StandardTypeLocator in StandardEvaluationContext: registering new import prefixes for use in Thymeleaf templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

We are developing a Spring MVC (v4) web app using the Thymeleaf templating library in the view layer with the Thymeleaf SpringTemplateEngine providing SPEL support.

When we reference types in our templates (e.g. for access to static utility methods or enums) we have to include the fully qualified name as the Spring **StandardEvaluationContext StandardTypeLocator** only knows about the java.lang package by default. I can see in the Spring API that we need to add our own packages to the type locator using the **registerImport(String prefix)** method, but I can't work out how to get hold of the default evaluation context that is used in our templates to be able to do this.

I want to de-clutter our Thymeleaf HTML templates by replacing this sort of thing:

```
T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).byteCountToDisplaySize(1024)
```

With:

```
T(FileUtils).byteCountToDisplaySize(1024)
```

I tried autowiring an EvaluationContext into a controller to see if I could get hold of it, but Spring tells me no qualifying beans are found. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JAVA based spring config. So in the spring security config class (There must be a @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) annotation) , I'm injecting a custom MethodSecurityExpressionHandler bean:

```
    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
      DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {

        @Override
        public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(final Authentication auth, final MethodInvocation mi) {

          StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = super.createEvaluationContextInternal(auth, mi);

          //Register custom package paths, since StandardTypeLocator is only aware of "java.lang"
          //So there will be no need to provide a fully qualified path
          ((StandardTypeLocator) evaluationContext.getTypeLocator()).registerImport("desired.path");

          return evaluationContext;
        }
      };

      expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new ExpressionAccessPermissionEvaluator()); //register some custom PermissionEvaluator if any
      return expressionHandler;
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but ThymeleafViewResolver class has addStaticVariable method which adds variables to the context before the view is processed.

I made a little test:

```
@Autowired
ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    thymeleafViewResolver.addStaticVariable("myUtil", new StringUtils());
}
```

With StringUtils like the below:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String print() {
        return "Printed";
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<div th:text="${T(some.package.StringUtils).print()}">Test</div>
<div th:text="${myUtil.print()}">Test</div>
```

Both worked fine. The latter will also work if your method is not static.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rafal, this is not exactly what I was looking for but is a useful workaround for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by wrapping the **EngineContextFactory** Class so I put as follow in my Thymeleaf config class:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine(SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver,
                                                                 IDialect springSecurityDialect)
{
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.setEngineContextFactory(engineContextFactory());
    templateEngine.addDialect(springSecurityDialect);
    return templateEngine;
}

private IEngineContextFactory engineContextFactory()
    {
        return new EngineContextFactoryWrapper()
            // packages to register
            .registerImport("java.util")
            .registerImport("java.math")
            .registerImport("com.mainsys.fhome.gui.util");
    }

public static class EngineContextFactoryWrapper
    implements IEngineContextFactory
{
    private final IEngineContextFactory delegate;
    private final List<String> typeLocatorPrefixes;

    public EngineContextFactoryWrapper()
    {
        super();
        delegate = new StandardEngineContextFactory();
        typeLocatorPrefixes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public IEngineContext createEngineContext(IEngineConfiguration configuration,
                                                            TemplateData templateData,
                                                            Map<String, Object> templateResolutionAttributes,
                                                            IContext context)
    {
        IEngineContext engineCtx = delegate.createEngineContext(configuration, templateData, templateResolutionAttributes, context);
        EvaluationContext evaluationContext;
        if (engineCtx.containsVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME))
        {
            evaluationContext = (EvaluationContext) engineCtx.getVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            evaluationContext = new ThymeleafEvaluationContextWrapper(new StandardEvaluationContext());
        }
        for (String prefix : typeLocatorPrefixes)
        {
            ((StandardTypeLocator) evaluationContext.getTypeLocator()).registerImport(prefix);
        }
        return engineCtx;
    }

    public EngineContextFactoryWrapper registerImport(String prefix)
    {
        typeLocatorPrefixes.add(prefix);
        return this;
    }
}
```